# base64 http post using iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, http-post

I want to post some binary data to a website.  The file can be somewhat large so I convert it to base64 and composite an url and post the url to the website with NSString stringWithContentsOfURL.

This works but it's really much slower than I think it should be. In part because my servers has a 2048 character url limit.   Is there a better way to post the data?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works but it's really much slower than I think it should be. In part because my servers has a 2048 character url limit. Is there a better way to post the data?

I would suggest using an actual POST request instead of cramming it into a sequence of GETs.

A short overview of the basics:

http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/HTTPPost/

Comment: your post is helpful, lets try and get that attitude to match.